# Putting additional pages on kohana framework

Tags: php, html, frameworks, kohana

I've started reading kohana documentation but didn't really understand, the index page I need to define in controllers like `public $template = "index";` but how do I add other `html, php` files as links? Because it doesn't find them if I simply put them in the view's folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public $template = "index"` means that `Controller_Template` class will load view from `views/index.php` file. You can add requred links directly to this file or dynamically - with template variables or subtemplates.

This wiki may help: http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php

Answer (score 1):

if you need to create a new page first you need to create a function in controller. also you need to assign the view file in that function.
For ex,
Here i ll create a user login page in user controller.

```
<?php
Class Controller_User extends Controller_Welcome
{
   /**For get User Login page**/
    public function action_login()
    {
        $view= View::factory('login');
        echo $view;     
    }
}
?>
```

login.php file is placed in application/views/login.php

Now your login page is called in the url like http://mysite.com/user/login/

If you want to call the page in a common template file , first you need to assign template file. then you can easily call the page in template file.

For ex,

```
user.php controller:

    <?php
    Class Controller_User extends Controller_Welcome
    {
       /**For get User Login page**/
        public function action_login()
        {
        $this->template='template.php';
            $view= View::factory('login');
        $this->template->content = $view;
        }
    }
    ?>

template.php view file:

        -- your html datas here --
        <?php  
            echo new View("header");
         ?>
        -- your html datas here --
        <?php  
                echo $content; ?>

        -- your html datas here --
        <?php  
                echo new View("footer");
         ?>
        -- your html datas here --
```

Here header is header.php, footer is footer.php. all these files are placed in applications/views/ folder.